# roscpp error listener.cpp and talker.cpp

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The same talker and listener works perfectly with a python file and why it fails to work with a cpp file.

```
rosrun ros_basic_tutorials talker.cpp
```

Error

> /home/ishan/catkin_ws/src/ros_basic_tutorials/src/talker.cpp:
> line 6: /bin: Is a directory
> /home/ishan/catkin_ws/src/ros_basic_tutorials/src/talker.cpp:
> line 7: listener.cpp: command not
> found
> /home/ishan/catkin_ws/src/ros_basic_tutorials/src/talker.cpp:
> line 8: */: No such file or directory
> /home/ishan/catkin_ws/src/ros_basic_tutorials/src/talker.cpp:
> line 9: syntax error near unexpected
> token `(' /home/ishan/catkin_ws/src/ros_basic_tutorials/src/talker.cpp: line 9:` int main(int argc, char
> **argv)'

talker.cpp

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"

#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  ros::init(argc, argv, "talker");



 ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("chatter", 1000);

  ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

  int count = 0;
  while (ros::ok())
  {
   
    std_msgs::String msg;

std::stringstream ss;
ss << "hello world " << count;
msg.data = ss.str();

ROS_INFO("%s", msg.data.c_str());

chatter_pub.publish(msg);

ros::spinOnce();

loop_rate.sleep();
++count;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347274/roscpp-error-listener.cpp-and-talker.cpp/) by [ishaniis](https://answers.ros.org/users/52219/ishaniis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can't run a .cpp file.

The command should be

```
rosrun beginner_tutorials talker
```

assuming you completed the section 3 Building your nodes of the WritingPublisherSubscriber(c++) tutorial

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2020-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ishaniis](https://answers.ros.org/users/52219/ishaniis/) on 2020-03-22**:
Ahaan!
Missing out on the important step.
Thank you so much.